# java Swing related for printing Table

Tags: java, swing, pdf

In swing , my jtable have 10 columns which i have to print in pdf format having 1 column as string format of 100 characters which overlapped to another column data. is there any way so that my data in that column print to next line.

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far

Comment: I SIMPLY MADE A jTABLE WHICH POPULATE DATA FROM DATABASE AND IN COLUMN % HAVE DATA OF 100 CAHARACTERS WHICH OVERLAP TO 6 COLUMN OR SO ON. IF U HAVE ANY SOLUTION PLZ HELP.

Comment: Can you share the code on how you are populating the values into tables